# NSTextAttachment Image Disappears When Attributes Are Set

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift

I'm having trouble applying attributes to `NSMutableAttributedString`s. If they have an image attachment, the image goes away when the attributes get added.

Take an `NSMutableAttributedString` that includes a text attachment, like this:

```
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello\n\n")
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = image    // some UIImage
let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
```

If I try to apply an attribute to the string, I lose the attachment:

```
let bodyFont = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
myString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: bodyFont], 
                       range: NSMakeRange(0, myString.length))
```

The string now appears with the right font but the attachment is gone. If I make the range `myString.length - 1` the attachment persists so I could probably step around any attachments with a little more work (maybe by looking for `NSTextAttachmentCharacter`). I'm wondering if there's something simpler I'm missing.

Comment: No. I wrote a method that applies styles to the text and just skips over `NSTextAttachmentCharacter`s if it finds them.

Comment: As I figured out using `addAttributes` makes all correct

Answer (score 12):

The solution for this is to not use `setAttributes:` but `addAttributes:` because it resets attributes that are set on the string initially. When generating an attributed string from a text attachment it sets some initial attributes that are needed to display the image.