# iOS - image attachment for the text view changes attributes

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitextview, nstextattachment

I've a `UITextView` described as follows with the given attributes:

```
lazy var inputTextView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.backgroundColor = .white
    tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12) // Posicionamento do texto

    let spacing = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    spacing.lineSpacing = 4
    let attr = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : spacing, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue]
    tv.typingAttributes = attr
    return tv
}()
```

Everything works as expected until I attach an image to the `UITextView`.

The image gets inserted in the desired position but after its inserted it overrides my `textView` attributes.

The text becomes small and in a different color than the attributes I've implemented in its declaration.

I'm attaching the image as follows:

```
    let att = NSTextAttachment()
    att.image = image
    let attrString = NSAttributedString(attachment: att)
    self.inputTextView.textStorage.insert(attrString, at: self.currentCursorLocation)
```

What's causing this issue?

I've even tried to reenforce its attributes whenever I insert an `UIImage` to its content.

I've tried the following when adding the image:

```
    let att = NSTextAttachment()
    att.image = image
    let attrString = NSAttributedString(attachment: att)
    self.inputTextView.textStorage.insert(attrString, at: self.currentCursorLocation)

    let spacing = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    spacing.lineSpacing = 4
    let attr = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : spacing, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue]
    self.inputTextView.typingAttributes = attr
```

And it still doesn't change its attributes.

Whats causing this issue? Any tip?

Thanks

### Edit

As suggested here's how I'm setting the cursor position

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    currentCursorLocation = textView.selectedRange.location
}
```

I do this to insert the image at the current location of the text blinking cursor

Comment: Might be from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391570/nstextattachment-image-disappears-when-attributes-are-set where poster says images use "set"

Comment: The thing is that I'm not setting attributes to the existing string, I've set the typing attributes initially and they work as expected but when I insert an image I lose my attributes and can't set them back neither

Comment: I believe you misinterpreted when I said the image is calling "set", so essentially yes, you are calling "set", because you call the image last, which overwrites your attributes. You're not directly calling it, but indirectly

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: Unfortunately this does not solve Ivan's problem - I leave the answer because it is interesting detail for those who do not understand Unicode character encoding].

String range specification is non-intuitive due to the subtleties of Unicode. I expect your issue is that the cursor position at which you are inserting your image is not where you think it is relative to the text and you are inserting the image at a Unicode scalar position that is not between Unicode code points, such that you are corrupting a unicode code. To understand why this can happen, see this Apple article.

[Strings in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30)

I would suggest using the following notation when specifying string ranges (taken from this Stack Overflow answer: [NSAttributedString and emojis: issue with positions and lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114872/nsattributedstring-and-emojis-issue-with-positions-and-lengths)).

```
// Convert to NSRange by computing the integer distances:
let nsRange = NSRange(location: text.utf16.distance(from: text.utf16.startIndex, to: from16),
                      length: text.utf16.distance(from: from16, to: to16))
```

However without seeing how you set your cursor position, it is not possible for me to be sure this is the source of your problem. [Update: thanks for updating the question to show the cursor position - we got there in the end but for others, note, after setting the cursor position this way (which would have been fine), he was incrementing it by 1, which meant the issue I have referred to about Unicode scalars versus code points was in fact the issue].

Comment: Whoa. Thanks for the explanation. I'll update the answer with the code setting the cursor.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm wrong! Since the position is set by the current cursor position function, it should be fine.

Comment: Then after inserting the image I increment the cursor by 1!

Comment: Ah, that could do it. Yes, by incrementing by 1, you are incrementing by one scalar position, which may not correspond with the next unicode code point.

Comment: Hmm.. I think you're right though. What's the best way to set the cursor position after inserting the Image? Count the text range and then reset the cursor to the last available location as I did before inserting it?

Comment: let index = text.utf16.index(text.utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: x)

Comment: I'll try it out then I'll @ you with feedback. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, see my previous edited comment, I gave a wrong direction and have now corrected it.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't solve my issue. Either I've miss read something or I cannot fix this.